# Disable Mouse Over focus in Windows 8 Metro Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am working on window8 metro application in this application i am inserting two image buttons,in simulator i am mouse mode pointer entered this time getting focus.

I am implementing this code ...

```
 private void button_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerEventArgs e)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pointer Entered");
     Button thisButton = (Button)sender;
     thisButton.Focus(FocusState.Unfocused);
 }
```

How can disable the focus on mouse pointer entered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows 8 Metro just yet, but you could try adding this:

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
```

That SHOULD stop any visualisations for mouseover and whatnot, but thats a WPF answer, it should work with metro, but no promises!